# TFS Code analysis rules could not be loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Setup:

a) TFS 2012 Team Project configured with Code Analysis (Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules) to run on check in.

b) VS 2012 solution whose projects reside under the Team Project folder structure in TFS(couple levels down the root).

c) All projects in the solution are configured to run the "Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules" on build

I am getting the following error on trying to check in the VS solution:
"One or more Code Analysis rules that are listed below could not be loaded. To pass the code analysis policy for this team project, all policy rules must be run on project with no vialations"

This is the same [error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/7437a090-d712-472f-a9ad-93d9f02b2db8/) reported here but the solution is not apparent.
I'm running on 64 bit Win 7 and I have validated that the ruleset file is present on my local machine at
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets"

What am I missing? Are there any settings/installs needed on the TFS server?

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm facing the same issue. I get an error about right name validation failing being the reason for failing to load for some of them, different errors for others.

Comment: I believe it was a syncing issue between VS and TFS. Did you try restarting VS?